# Column updating with Tabpy in Tableau Desktop

Tags: python, tableau-desktop, tabpy

I don't know why my column is not updating while my Tabpy is connected with Tableau even with the easiest requests possible
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8tNs.png)

My Tableau version is 2020.1 and my Tabpy version is 2.6.0

I was primarly running Tabpy on my mac and Tableau on my Vm but I redid all the process with Tabpy on the Vm. The connection is working but there is no response in the column.

I tried to restart all Tableau, Tabpy a million times and computer too plus asking ChatGPT a lot until it returns me the same responses again and again.
I also used this fonction to test :

```
    SCRIPT_STR("
lst= []
for i in range(0,len(_arg1)) :
        lst.append(_arg1[i]+', Hello from Python (direct)!')
return lst
",
ATTR([Col1])
)
```

I tried all tutorials but nobody has that problem at that state (when the connexion is verified)

Comment: try updating to Tableau 2023.1, it has better support for Python

Comment: I got the same problem with Tableau 2023 sadly..

Comment: Can you post what your console is outputting? There might be an error in there that's not showing up in your Tableau window.

Comment: @sanminchui : '2023-04-26,16:15:04 [INFO] (app.py:app:110): Web service listening on port 9004      
2023-04-26,16:17:44 [INFO] (base_handler.py:base_handler:115): Authentication is not a required feature for API "v1"
2023-04-26,16:17:44 [INFO] (base_handler.py:base_handler:115): Authorization header not found
2023-04-26,16:17:44 [INFO] (web.py:web:2327): 200 GET /info (::1) 4.98ms'; thx for your time man